# Add multiple PostgreSQL enum values with one command

Tags: postgresql, enums

Since PostgreSQL 9.1 enum values can be added using

```
ALTER TYPE my_type ADD VALUE new_value;
```

However, trying to run this as part of a bigger script gives an error:

**ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string**

This makes it a real hassle to script changes to be applied in production, because support staff have to remember that, while most scripts can be run "normally", there are a few "special" scripts that need to be opened in pgAdmin and run manually, piece by piece. I've Googled this and I understand the limitation - enum values cannot be added inside a transaction or part of a "multi-command string". That's OK. I don't need to do that. I just want to add multiple enum values and execute other, unrelated, SQL statements without having to feed Postgres one statement at a time.

In other words: I want to be able to run a single script, both from pgAdmin and from psql, that simply does the same thing that pgAdmin does when I highlight one line at a time and press F5 (run). Is there a way to do this, maybe with plpgsql?

Comment: Why don't you use a check constraint instead of an enum. Much more flexible (and portable). `alter type add value` cannot run in a transaction, so all you need to do is to turn off auto-commit before those statements (I don't know how to do that in pgAdmin, I don't use it)

Comment: `psql -f the_script` will work just fine.

Comment: You're right, Craig Ringer, "psql -f" already works.


a_horse_with_no_name, yes, maybe disabling autocommit would do the trick, but I can't find a way to do that (without starting a transaction myself). `SET AUTOCOMMIT = OFF` gives an error: "SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported" How does "psql -f" do it then? Does it parse the script itself and send it to the server one statement at a time?

Comment: did you found the solution for this?
I have the issue with it too when want to run a big script

Comment: @Kostanos No, but PostgreSQL 12 should allow this (not tested, just read the docs).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this will finally be fixed in PostgreSQL 12.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertype.html says

> If ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE (the form that adds a new value to an enum type) is executed inside a transaction block, the new value cannot be used until after the transaction has been committed.